# AFNetworking Reachability not recognizing internet connection for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using `AFNetworking Reachability` in few views in this app. In one view, there is strange problem. In every view, I've started monitoring in `loadView`: `[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring]`, and calling isReachable in `viewDidLoad`: `if([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].isReachable)`.

Every time, it returns NO, like there is no internet connection, and I'm pretty sure I have stable wireless connections(working in another views).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AFNetworking framework the `startMonitoring` method runs in `Background global queue`.

In your case `ViewDidLoad` method gets called before the completion of `startMonitoring` method because it is running in different queue.

So instead checking the `isReachable` flag use reachabilityStatusChangeBlock like following

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unkown network status");

    }

}];
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

Comment: How can I implement this in case of rootViewController, where I only need to check is there connection?

Comment: You can put this code in RootViewController ViewDidLoad method. If the case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable or default is called then there is no network connection. But implement this in AppDelegate would be an ideal way.

Answer (score 2):

`[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]` is a singleton and it is initialized when you make call to it for the first time, and it will live while the app live.

Also it is need some time to check if the ethernet/wifi `isReachable`.

So you can put this code :

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

to `AppDelegate` and just check the ethernet connection whenever you need.